# how to convert Binary(application/octet-stream) to a text file in using python

Tags: python

I have Binary (application/octet-stream) file in Linux I want to read it as normal text file and grep/capture some lines using python. How can I do so? As I am not able to find any solution for it which works for me.

My code is

```
f=open(file_path_log,"rb")
for lines in f:
    lines = lines.encode("utf-8")
    lines = lines.strip()
    #print lines
    if "Max" in lines:
        print "in"
        print text , 'Text'
```

Comment: did yor try `print lines.decode("utf-8")` ?

Comment: Yes I tried the above command but it is not working

Comment: why are you opening the file in 'rb' mode? If you are reading a file that contains only strings, you need to use 'r' instead of 'rb'.

Comment: Use decode instead of encode.

Comment: hi what is this `text`  in the if condition ? and did you try
`str(lines)` instead of encoding ?

Comment: hey text is just a "heloo" string which I had written for testing purpose And I tried str(lines) the output is as follows "1\000/\0001\0006\000/\0002\0000\0001\0008\000 "